# Error: array subscript out of range for i+2 years

Tags: if-statement, sas, sas-studio

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
ID      2017    2018    2019    2020

2017    30      24      20      18
2018    30      24      20      18
2019    30      24      20      18
2020    30      24      20      18
```

I am looking to create an array based on a few inputs:

```
%let FixedorFloating = '1 or 0';
%let Repricingfrequency = n Years;
%let LastRepricingDate = 'Date'n;
```

The array criteria is such that if ID= Year +2i then flag = 1

e.g.

```
ID = 2017 then flag =1 for Years 2017 and 2019, 0 otherwise

ID = 2018 then flag = 1 for Years 2018 and 2020, 0 otherwise

ID = 2019 then flag = 1 for Year 2019 , 0 otherwise

ID = 2020 then flag = 1 for year 2020, 0 otherwise
```

My code is currently, I'm having issues with year i+2 (highlighted in red) but year(i) works fine.

```
data ReferenceRateContract;
    set refratecontract;

 *arrays for years and flags;
     array _year(2017:2022) year2017-year2022;
     array _flag(2017:2022) flag2017-flag2022;
```

*loop over array;

```
if &FixedorFloating=1

    then do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);

    /*check if year matches year in variable name*/

    if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i)),, 'kd') 
        then _flag(i)=1;

    else _flag(i)=0;

end;

else if &fixedorfloating=0

    then do i=&dateoflastrepricing to hbound(_year);

    if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i)),, 'kd') 
        then _flag(i)=1;

    else if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i+2)),, 'kd') 
    then _flag(i)=1;

    else _flag(i)=0;
end;

drop i;
```

run;

```
data referenceratecontract;
set referenceratecontract;
keep flag2017--flag2020;
run;
```

Looking for a way to flag based on Id= Year + 2i, TIA

```
***else if put(ID, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i+2)),, 'kd') then _flag(i)=1;***
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I should have put `I - 2` instead of `I + 2`

also, I had to change my array limits as my hbound was trying to iterate to the end of the matrix.